# Scaling SCNPhysicsVehicleWheels before importing them into Xcode

Tags: xcode, scenekit, collada

There have already been asked quite a few questions how to properly handle too big SCNPhysicsVehicleWheels within SceneKit. 
I tried scaling my .dae model beforehand in Blender (by setting up the scale, unit & metric system), also in Unity & Xcode SceneKit Editor (by setting the scale in the Node inspector) but wasn't able to resolve this issue. 
I also tried setting the unit tag within the .dae source file as well. However the wheels of my model are always too big. What am I missing? Thanks a lot in advance for any hints!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you scale the models down in Blender, you need to Apply the scale.  When you scale something in blender, its dimensions are adjusted but so is it's scale.  When you apply the scale, the new dimension is maintained but the scale factor is set back to 1.0.  To apply the scale go to the Object menu > Apply > Scale.

Maybe you knew this but I thought it wouldn't hurt to point out because it got me.

Comment: Thanks so much for sharing this insight with me — I finally had the time to check your suggestion & it worked out of the box!